# How to change boot login

Tags: startup, login

How Do I change the user for the Boot login? I had changed my username recently and have deleted the temporary admin that has been made to change my username, but the Boot Login has somehow changed to the temporary admin.

Is there any way to change the Boot Login so that I don't have to deal with putting in two passwords everytime I turn on my macbook?

Comment: EDIT: As you turn on your macbook, upon booting on, it would ask you for the password and it will load up the mac. THAT is NOT the User selection screen.

Comment: youtube video for description: [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ffeomBeEvc]

Answer (score 1):

You can set which account is automatically logged in under the "Login Options" section of the "Users & Groups" pane of System Preferences:
[image]

Comment: I didn't want for automatic login - just added comments to my question. take a look at the youtube video to see what I mean.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with the idea of "boot login". How did you originally configure this? Perhaps it was a "firmware password", as discussed here: http://osxdaily.com/2014/01/06/set-firmware-password-mac/

Comment: happened when changing my username from "AntCab" to "__________" - the temporary admin used to change it was "jytred" - However after deleting jytred, it has seemed to remain upon boot

Comment: I also found out about this since the upgrade to Yosemite. I never had a Boot login before until the Upgrade.

Comment: I mean how did you originally configure the requirement for a special password that then system requires you to enter upon boot? Requiring a password *before* the login screen, as I believe you describe, is not the normal Mac behaviour. How did you originally configure this? Was it through the "firmware password" I described in my previous comment? If so, follow the instructions in the link I posted to change the boot password settings.

Comment: Like I said, I never had this setting before until the upgrade to Yosemite. I had never accessed safe mode before. Before the upgrade, it had loaded up WITHOUT asking for the password, and had always loaded up the login screen.